# Find the roots of $\left(\frac{z-2}{z+2}\right)^5=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a complex number question I'm struggling with:

find the roots of $$\left(\frac{z-2}{z+2}\right)^5=1$$
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: $$y^5=w^5\iff y=e^{2ik\pi/5} w\quad\text{for some integer }0\le k<5$$

Answer (score 1):

If you let $w = \frac{z - 2}{z + 2}$, then you have an equation of the form $w^5 = 1$. So $w$ is a fifth root of unity. For notation's sake, define $\zeta = \exp(2 \pi i / 5)$, and note that you must have $w = \zeta^k$ for $k \in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}$. Therefore, you have $\frac{z - 2}{z + 2} = \zeta^k$.

From here, just rearrange and solve for $z$.